# Processing Cobol files and Workbooks in PHP

Tags: php, api, cobol

I had previously posted a question on translating custom COBOL files without copybooks.  I was recently able to get the copybooks for these files and I'm now looking into another possible solution.

Ideally what we'd like to do is create a PHP module that can receive these custom COBOL file types and using the accompanying copybooks translate these into fields in a database that can be uploaded on a daily basis.

Does anyone have any experience parsing custom COBOL files in PHP?

Thanks,

This is for a new development.

Comment: There is no "COBOL file" - what do you want to actually access via PHP? An indexed file (then you're out of luck), a sequential [binary] file? Please answer those questions (in your question) and edit the link to your recent question in, which may help to get a picture about the issue and the previous answers/comments.

Comment: If you can run the files with COBOL on the command line, I'd use Symfony Process to run the file normally and capture the output into a file or buffer PHP can access.

Comment: Wherever these files come from make sure that all numeric fields have the  display characteristic i.e. that they are not COMP (binary) of COMP-3 (packed decimal). Probably your only other concerns would be arrays - either of fixed length or varying length.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.  As Simon pointed out these are not COBOL file's so to speak but rather written in COBOL in fixed-length with accompanying copybooks for translation (the actual file types are custom).  What we'd like to do via PHP is basically translate these custom files into a readable form (like XML) that we can use within the software.  I know that COBOL to XML and COBOL to CSV programs exist but we'd like the PHP to do this for us so that we can simply upload the custom COBOL files and the software will then translate them and enter them in our database.

Comment: @user3062109 so you want to take a copybook and translate each record of a file into something based usable in PHP?

Comment: @SaggingRufus that's nearly what he said he wanted to do: create a "parser" for fixed length files to do the conversion in php, then provide a web-frontend to upload fixed-length files to convert them upon request (I'd guess after choosing the appropriate parser).

Comment: @user3062109 "I know that COBOL to XML and COBOL to CSV programs exist but we'd like the PHP to do this for us so that we can simply upload the custom COBOL files and the software will then translate them and enter them in our database." Why not using COBOL (zero parsing necessary) with a web-fronted [easiest option is running it as CGI module]?

Comment: I suggest using "tool" what it can do best: If PHP should be "in charge" maybe provide a PHP front-end to upload the data, `proc_open` a COBOL process, passing the filename as option, reading the data and `DISPLAY` JSON/XML data which you then parse in PHP and write back to the DB?
In this case you have COBOL for COBOL-files (per record) to XML/JSON, PHP for JSON/XML to DB and web-communication.